# jQuery .each is giving different results on different browsers but no errors. It counts the elements wrong, but why?

Tags: jquery, arrays, cross-browser, push, each

I need to add the one attribute of all of a certain element to an array:

Here is the html:

```
<a class="umb" name="/wordpress/images/custom-slideshow/image1.jpg">  
<a class="umb" name="/wordpress/images/custom-slideshow/image2.jpg">  
<a class="umb" name="/wordpress/images/custom-slideshow/image3.jpg">
```

Here is the jQuery

```
var theImages = new Array();

$('.umb').each(function(){

    theImages.push($(this).attr('name'));

});

alert(theImages.length);
```

this alerts different numbers in different browsers
in Firefox "15"
in IE8 "3"
in Chrome "6"
in Opera "3"
in Safari "12"

The right answer is of course "3". Can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: What you posted isn't valid HTML, what does your actual HTML look like?

Comment: For one thing, have you noticed that they are all multiples of 3?

Which begs the question, *when is the code getting executed*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well on a quick test of this I get 3 in Safari 5, but it could be because different browsers will attempt to correct the unclosed anchor tags in different ways (assuming that wasn't a paste error).  Each anchor should should have a </a> at the end.

Comment: I would still like to know why the browsers count it differently.